# Query for information from a DWG file

Tags: autocad, autodesk-designautomation

We would like to extract floor plan information (room types, dimensions, and other elements) from an existing dwg file using the Design Automation API for Autocad /Revit. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Design Automation service is used to execute *your* custom plugins on Autodesk servers, so if you have a custom AutoCAD or Revit plugin that can extract this kind of information then yes, you can create a Design Automation pipeline that will execute the plugin for any files you send to it. For more information, check out the tutorial at https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/.